# Error al compilar en Android Studio Unable to merge dex

Tags: java, android

**Hola a todos**, estoy tratando de compilar mi app, pero me muestra este error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

este es mi build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.websmithing.gpstracker"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 15
        versionName "4.0.5"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Realizaste alguna actualización o cambio en tu build.gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes de agregar `multiDexEnabled true` en android -> defaultonfig

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.websmithing.gpstracker"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 15
       multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "4.0.5"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Este link puede explicar porque usar multiDexEnabled true [multiDesx](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#avoid). Basicamente cuando la app tiene demaciadas dependencias mas de 64k se producen errores de compilación. Por eso se debe activar esa opción.